# Pandas calculate elapsed time

Tags: pandas, group-by, split-apply-combine

```
data = [    
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-26 09:36:47'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER01'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-26 11:01:55'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER01'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 10:01:20'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 14:46:09'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 13:27:57'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER01'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 18:03:09'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER01'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'),'User', 'LicenseCode'])
```

Hi guys, I'd like to create a new elapsed time column (in hours) for licenses from the sample data of license checkout. This is just a snippet of 500k+ lines.

Conditions for new column:

- elapsed time will be grouped by day, user & license code as only elapsed time for each day will be tabulated for each unique user & licensecode
- if df['Action'] == OUT, elapsed time = 0
- if (df['Action'] == OUT) & (df['Action'].shift() == OUT), elapsed time = df[DateTime].diff()
- if 'Action' == IN, elapsed time = calculate cumulative time diff of previous 'OUT' line (they work in pairs OUT then IN)
- **there are instances of OUT,OUT,IN,IN (order of 'Action' rows), most ideal will be OUT,IN,OUT,IN**

I've hit a wall when I try to do a groupby agg with a custom function as I can't reference the columns by e.g. df['Action'].

Example of Desired Output :

| DateTime | Action | LicenseCode | User | Elapsed_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-26 09:36:47 | OUT | APP01 | USER01 | 0.00 |
| 2023-09-26 11:36:47 | IN | APP01 | USER01 | 2.00 |
| 2023-09-27 09:30:00 | OUT | APP02 | USER02 | 0.00 |
| 2023-09-27 14:30:00 | IN | APP02 | USER02 | 5.00 |
| 2023-09-27 15:30:00 | OUT | APP02 | USER02 | 5.00 |
| 2023-09-27 15:45:00 | IN | APP02 | USER02 | 5.25 |
| 2023-09-27 16:10:00 | OUT | APP01 | USER02 | 0.00 |
| 2023-09-27 16:40:00 | IN | APP01 | USER02 | 0.50 |
| 2023-09-27 17:00:00 | OUT | APP01 | USER02 | 0.50 |
| 2023-09-27 17:12:00 | OUT | APP01 | USER02 | 0.70 |
| 2023-09-27 17:42:00 | IN | APP01 | USER02 | 1.20 |
| 2023-09-27 17:52:00 | IN | APP01 | USER02 | 1.37 |

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Panda Kim, I've managed to retrieve the desired output. Here is the code modification from @Panda Kim's input.

**Code:**

```
data = [    
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-26 09:36:47'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER01'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-26 11:36:47'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER01'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 09:30:00'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 14:30:00'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 15:30:00'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 15:45:00'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP02', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 16:10:00'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 16:40:00'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 17:00:00'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 17:12:00'), 'Action': 'OUT', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 17:42:00'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'},
            {'DateTime': pd.to_datetime('2023-09-27 17:52:00'), 'Action': 'IN', 'LicenseCode': 'APP01', 'User': 'USER02'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cond = (df['Action'].eq('OUT')) & (df['Action'].shift(+1).eq('IN'))
grp = cond.groupby([df['LicenseCode'],df['User']]).cumsum()
df['elapsed_time'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'), grp, 'User', 'LicenseCode'])['DateTime'].diff()
df['elapsed_time'] = df['elapsed_time'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
df['elapsed_time'] = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'),'User', 'LicenseCode']).elapsed_time.cumsum() \
    .dt.total_seconds()/3600)  \
    .round(2)

print(df)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If you want the following output, use the following code.
If the desired output is different from the following, please provide the desired output clearly as a text table.

Also, **your example has a typo** and cannot run it.

**Code**

```
cond = df['Action'].eq('OUT')
grp = cond.groupby(df['LicenseCode']).cumsum()
df['elapsed time'] = df.groupby([grp, 'LicenseCode'])['DateTime'].diff().mask(cond, 0)
```

df:

```
             DateTime Action LicenseCode    User     elapsed time
0 2023-09-26 09:36:47    OUT       APP01  USER01                0
1 2023-09-26 11:01:55     IN       APP01  USER01  0 days 01:25:08
2 2023-09-27 10:01:20    OUT       APP02  USER02                0
3 2023-09-27 14:46:09     IN       APP02  USER02  0 days 04:44:49
4 2023-09-27 13:27:57    OUT       APP02  USER01                0
5 2023-09-27 18:03:09     IN       APP02  USER01  0 days 04:35:12
```

Comment: appreciate your reply, I've edited my original post :)